# JavaScript equivalent to the Java Import statement

Tags: javascript

I'm using JavaScript Development Tools in Eclipse.  What is the equivalent to the Java import statement?

I'm particularly interested in being able to navigate with F3 (`Open Declaration`).

Code in site would be nice, too.

Comment: The [JavaScript `import` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import), of course. Though it only works in certain environments. You probably refer to a browser context?

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="/link/to/js/file"></script>
```

Comment: I'm still trying to get Eclipse to recognize the script html element above then I can accept your answer.  I'm hoping to use F3 to navigate from one `.js` file to another.  I'm wondering if my project setup is incorrect or maybe my question is not clear.